# How do I write a select_year backwards from today's year?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, forms

I understand there is a select_Year but i can't figure out how to use it:

```
= f.select_year("dob", :start_year => DateTime.now.year, :end_year => DateTime.now.year - 100 )
```

This is incorrect..how would you actually write this? My attribute is `:dob`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
= f.select_year(Date.today, :start_year => DateTime.now.year, :end_year => DateTime.now.year - 100, :field_name => 'dob' )
```

**EDIT**

next one works

```
select_year(Date.today, {:start_year => DateTime.now.year, :end_year => DateTime.now.year - 100}, {:name => 'card_signup[dob]'})
```

Comment: ahh! field_name! i'm surprised the API had no documentation on such an important field. Thanks!

Comment: @Bohdan, Field_Name is actually incorrect I think. Because it parses as  date["dob"], and not myModel["dob"] . What's missing?

Comment: Hmm I ended up going with `= date_select("card_signup", "dob", :end_year => DateTime.now.year - 100, :discard_day => true, :discard_month => true)`

Comment: I suppose if you need such field you should better use date_select("model", "dob", :start_year => DateTime.now.year, :end_year => DateTime.now.year - 100, :discard_month => true,
                                    :discard_day => true)

Comment: I'm not sure but you also may try select_year(Date.today, {:start_year => DateTime.now.year, :end_year => DateTime.now.year - 100}, {:name => 'card_signup[dob]'} )

Comment: That last one turned out right in the HTML, but I guess it was missing something or other because it failed validation as being a blank field. The working one `<select name="card_signup[dob(1i)]" id="card_signup_dob_1i">` , and the non-working one, `<select name="card_signup[dob]" id="date_year">`

Comment: I tried using this but wanted to add a `:prompt`. It isn't working for some reason. Anyone have any ideas? Here's the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7060216/issue-with-prompt-in-select-year-with-start-end-year