# Issue with ":prompt" in select_year with start/end_year

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, date

Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3971164/how-do-i-write-a-select-year-backwards-from-todays-year) as a guide, I set out to create a `select_year` that started with today's year and ends 100 years ago. But I wanted to add a `:prompt` so that the drop down starts with "Year" instead of the current year. So I used the following:

```
<%= select_year(Date.today, {:prompt => "Year", :start_year => DateTime.now.year, :end_year => DateTime.now.year - 115}, {:field_name => 'Year', :id => 'Date.year'}) %>
```

This renders a drop down for year, but the prompt shows current year instead of "Year". If I click the drop down though, it shows "Year" as the first option with current year selected. How can I fix this? What did I do wrong?

**UPDATE:** Here is the HTML output of the above code:

```
<select field_name="Year" id="Date.year" name="date[year]">
<option value="">Year</option>
<option selected="selected" value="2011">2011</option>
```

How can I make it so 2011 isn't automatically `"selected"`?

Comment: Yeah, I'll add the HTML output (the relevant parts at least) to the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

solution was simple

```
    <%= select_year(0, {:prompt => "Year", 
                        :start_year => DateTime.now.year, 
                        :end_year => DateTime.now.year - 115}, 
                       {:field_name => 'Year', :id => 'Date.year'}) %>
```

I suppopse if default value is out of range you have first of the list selected which is prompt

Comment: Great, thanks so much! I'll have to read back over things to figure out how all this is structured.