# Date of Birth UI element in Ruby on Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I've used Ruby on Rails 3 to generate scaffolding for a model including Date of Birth as a date native type. However, the default UI element for the year only gives you the option of +- 5 years from the current year, meaning the range is limited to 2006-2016.

Is there an elegant way to restrict this range to all years before the current year?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I write a select_year backwards from today's year?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3971164/how-do-i-write-a-select-year-backwards-from-todays-year)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
<%= select_year(Date.today, :start_year => 1992, :end_year => 2011) %>
```

see [this](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-select_year).